# Not able to get MAC address of client machine using php

Tags: php, apache, server, cloud, mac-address

Unable to get mac address of client machine when my application is hosted on cloud. Code is working fine on localhost but fails to get MAC address when i deploy it on cloud server. Tried too many codes like this.

```
function GetMacAddress()
{
    $MAC = exec('getmac');
    return $MAC = strtok($MAC, ' ');
}
```

Comment: When you say *get mac address of client machine*, do you mean the server the code is running on or the MAC address of the end user?

Comment: Application is hosted on server and accessed by end user, i want mac address of end user's machine.